# Historical African Demographic and Agriculture Data

Tags: africa, agriculture, demography, colony

I'm looking for resources that give the the demographic breakdown of African nations for the time period 1880-1960 (so colonization), such as from censuses. Primarily, I need the european share of the population. Is anyone aware of various sources that are available that include this information? I'm willing to spend the time to digitize, but am a little lost where to even begin.

I'm also interested in agriculture production or exports for the pre-colonial period, particularly pre-1866. Again, I'm unsure where to even begin with this research. Any ideas?

Comment: For British colonies, you should be able to find some information from the relevant British Imperial Census prior to independence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an open ended source request.

Comment: I agree that the question is open ended. But it's interesting and could mobilise a lot of people. On the upside there's at least the time period that's clear. If the question could be more precise, including a model to include all the answers (the data will be very heterogeneous), it would be worthwhile. There's been a lot of work done on this area. One last caution: the presence of Europeans was used to justify claims, possession being 9/10 of the law. So, figures from the late 19th century up to the thirties at least will have to be taken with care.